# How can I stop jquery ui dialog executes on pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an input field that I have bound an event on keypressed, but when I press Enter (to execute the event for the input) two dialogs from jQuery UI pops open and ruin my variables. How can I stop the events bound to the enter key for dialogs?

```
$("#itemSample").on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $("#itemSample").val().trim().length > 0) {
        //do something               
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the parameter 'e' (Event) you have the necessary functions:

```
$("#itemSample").on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $("#itemSample").val().trim().length > 0) {
      // You probably need just one of the following two lines:
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();           
    }
});
```

For more info: http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/